Error in Expo Router (Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component. )
I’m having an issue with my project, specifically with the buttons and navigation. When I press any button on the UI (except for the Tabs, which I want to keep), I get the following error: 'Uncaught Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component. Ensure the Root Layout component is rendering a Slot, or other navigator on the first render.' I don't understand why this is happening.enter image description here I’m leaving a link to a video about the navigation and the problem, as well as my GitHub repository 
I tried to use another forms to change the screen (router.push, link, router.replace, href)
